# Issues while creating repository?

Tags: git, github, repository, bitbucket

Hi I am new to Bitbucket.

1. In the beginning, while setting up the account I am asked to enter the email ids...do at that time I have to enter just my email id or the email ids of all the people that I am sharing my code with.
2. While setting up my code repository I am using the following steps:

   ```
   mkdir ABCproject
   cd ABCproject
   git init
   touch README
   git add README
   git commit -m 'first commit'
   git remote add origin https://bitbucket.com/USERabc/rdf-project.git
   git push -u origin master
   ```

   But in these steps I am not getting where exactly do I have to put the my code, which I am sharing. Do I have to myself put my code within the ABCproject folder?

   And the statement `git push -u origin master` gives me the error: `fatal: https://bitbucket.com/USERabc/ABCproject/ABCproject.git/info/refs not found: did you run git update-server-info on the server?"`
3. For pushing the repo..I am using the following commands,

   ```
   git remote add origin git@github.com:USERabc/ABCproject.git
   $ git push origin master
   ```

   It's still giving me the same error...(the error is the same as above). What is the meaning of the above statement.

I am new to bitbucket. CAN SOMEONE BE KING ENOUGH TO HELP ME OUT??? (I have my code stored on my pc and I want to share the code with my friends.)

Comment: Why is your origin `github.com` if you are using `bitbucket.com`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your repository is where you put in your code. The repository contains all files and their complete history. It is what you create when typing `git init`. So yeah, it is the `ABCproject` folder.

To actually add files to the repository (after moving the files into it), you need to add them to the history, similar to what you did with the `README` file. You should refer to some Git tutorials on how to do it, and what you can do.

Next, as alex already pointed out, you are talking about bitbucket but use a GitHub URL. The correct URL should be `https://<user>@bitbucket.org/<user>/abcproject.git`. Note that when using a `git@bitbucket.org:…` or `git@github.com:…` remote, you are using SSH for which you need to setup SSH keys first (the site’s help sections do explain that pretty well).

Finally, it seems that the repository you are trying to push to simply does not exist. So before pushing, create the repository on the site. After doing that you should also get a mini tutorial on how to add the (correct) remote to an existing repository and push it correctly. Follow that, and you should be fine.

In general, I’d suggest you to take a look at the [bitbucket 101](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/bitbucket+101) tutorial, especially the [“Create an Account and a Git Repo” part](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Create+an+Account+and+a+Git+Repo). For general Git help, you should read the [Git book](http://git-scm.com/book) (at least the first two chapters).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Bitbucket, you need to read Bitbucket instructions, not something from Github. See the steps [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Set+up+Git+and+Mercurial).

They're not very different, but you need to add your origin to point to bitbucket repo url, not something from github.

As to your question where to put your code, you either

- Create a new folder for source control and put your files there, or
- Use your existing folder where you have the code, and do "git init" and "git add" commands in that folder

You probably want to do the latter.